# Proving Hall's marriage theorem using Sperner's lemma

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, graph-theory, matching-theory

In the paper [Hall's theorem for hypergraphs (Aharoni and Haxell, 2000)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/1097-0118(200010)35:2%3C83::AID-JGT2%3E3.0.CO;2-V),
the authors prove a theorem on the existence of perfect matchings in bipartite hypergraphs, using Sperner's lemma. At the last page (6), they say that "we have here a topological proof of Hall's theorem" (for bipartite graphs). I thought it should be easy to write this proof explicitly, since a simple bipartite graph is just a bipartite hypergraph in which each hyperedge is of size 2. But there is a problem: during the proof, the authors assume that the sets of neighbors (i.e., the sets $N(x)$ for each vertex $x\in X$, where $X$ is one part of the hypergraph) are pairwise-disjoint. For a hypergraph, this assumption is without loss of generality, since we can add dummy vertices to edges, and this does not affect the theorem conditions or concludion. But in a graph, we cannot add vertices to edges.

So my question is: is there an explicitly-written proof of Hall's marriage theorem, using Sperner's lemma (or a similar topological theorem)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Penny Haxell's 2011 paper [On Forming Committees](https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.118.09.777) in the American Mathematical Monthly explicitly uses Sperner's lemma to prove Hall's theorem for bipartite graphs (see theorem 4.1 and 4.2).

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Carlo Beenakker's answer that gives Hall via Sperner directly, I think you can also get it by applying Hall's Theorem for Hypergraphs as follows. Let $G$ be a bipartite graph with partite sets $X, Y$, and write $V(X) = \{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$. For each $i$, define a $1$-uniform hypergraph $H_i$ with vertex set $N(x_i)$ and edge set $\{ \{y\} : y \in N(x_i) \}$.

Letting $\mathcal{A} = \{H_1, \ldots, H_n\}$, we see that $\mathcal{A}$ has a disjoint set of representatives if and only if $G$ has a matching that saturates $X$. Now the condition of Aharoni and Haxell's Theorem 1.1 applied to the family $\mathcal{A}$ is clearly equivalent to Hall's Condition on $G$. Since classical Hall's Theorem falls out of the hypergraph version so quickly, I think it's fair to think of the topological proof of the hypergraph version as also being a topological proof of Hall's theorem.